# Facebook graph API obtain a specific users's pictures from that same user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm working on an Android application and I'm trying to obtain contact pictures from friends. I'm still testing the graph request on the **Facebook Graph API Explorer** [linkhere](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) I'm going to use afterwards in the code, and I've hit a snag...

After generating an Access Token, and validating it allows me access to the correct fields I'm interested, I'm trying to filter the information I'm obtaining from Facebook.

Using the **Facebook Graph API Explorer** I'm performing the following request:

> < USER_ID>?fields=id,first_name,last_name,location,picture,birthday,photos.limit(3).fields(id,picture,source,from)

I obtain, as expected:

```
{
"id": "<USER_ID>", 
"first_name": "<FIRST>", 
"last_name": "<LAST>", 
"photos": {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "<PICTURE1>", 
      "source": "<PIC1.jpg>", 
    "from": {
      "name": "<OTHER_USER1>", 
      "id": "<OTHER_USER1_ID>"
    }, 
    "created_time": "2013-08-17T11:39:19+0000"
  }, 
  {
    "id": "<PICTURE2>", 
    "source": "<PIC2.jpg>", 
    "from": {
      "name": "<OTHER_USER2>", 
      "id": "<OTHER_USER2_ID>"
    }, 
    "created_time": "2013-08-04T14:27:07+0000"
  }, 
  {
    **"id": "<PICTURE3>"**, 
    "source": "<PIC3.jpg>", 
    "from": {
      "name": "<USER>", 
      **"id": "<USER_ID>"**
    }, 
    "created_time": "2013-08-03T17:35:20+0000"
  }
], 
"paging": {
  "previous": "<LINK1>", 
  "next": "<LINK2>"
}
}, 
"picture": {
"data": {
  "url": "<PIC>", 
  "is_silhouette": false
 }
}
}
```

What I would like is to only obtain the pictures `from`  ... like the third picture or others, is this possible using the graph api?

**Thanks for the help.**

Marc

PS:
I've tried adding in the end something like &photos.data.from.id=< USER_ID>
but I till get the same data set in response.
I would like to avoid requesting more pictures and filter it programmatically, because You never know how many pictures are associated with a user that where not submitted by that user.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what result are you expecting

Comment: I wanted to obtain only photos from a specific user, case in point the photos uploaded/added from the friend whose data I'm browsing.
So on the result above I wanted to not receive PICTURE1 and PICTURE2, only PICTURE3 and maybe 2 more pictures that had id": "<USER_ID>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with the `Graph API`, but you can use [**FQL**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/), to query for the photos of the user (not those in which he's tagged in) -

```
SELECT pid,src FROM photo WHERE owner = me()
```

Check [FQL - Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/) to include the required fields in the result.

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much (not being able with graph API).